# What are the plotX, plotY values of a point in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

What are the plotX, plotY values of a point in HighCharts? I can't find them in the documentation. I read the values but couldn't make sense of them when using a pixel ruler on the graph.

Answer (score 4):

plotX and plotY are not part of API - just inner properties to get coordinates where plot point. Using them is shorthand for getting values from point:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.x
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.y

And translating to position via:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels()

Comment: Highcharts is the deepest of all rabbit holes. You will go in circles and circles for hours.  plotX and PlotY are shown in this official fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-label-on-chart/ Ironically this is exactly what I am trying to do. Unfortunately label's x and y parameters cannot be deduced from plotX and Y or any of the of the point series

Comment: If you have any problems it's the best to contact Highcharts support, or write a question. I would like to help you, but your comment doesn't tell me what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: The answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273985/how-to-position-a-custom-label-in-highcharts/44274149#44274149

Answer (score 2):

plotX and plotY are the reference point in the plot area, chart.plotLeft and chart.plotTop get the full coordinates.

Check the API for tooltip->positioner
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9L5j/

```
tooltip: {
    positioner: function () {
        return { x: 80, y: 50 };
    }
}
```