# How to position a custom label in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to do exactly what is in this official HighCharts fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-label-on-chart/

However the example's "label" function has hardcoded the x(270) and y(50) parameters:

```
function (chart) { // on complete
var point = chart.series[0].points[8];
chart.renderer.label('Max observation', 270, 50, 'callout',
point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)
```

My chart obviously will require different parameters. I tried using point's plotX etc. However these are undocumented. in fact the are are not part of API as a (presumably) HighCharts developer points out in another answer - they are just inner properties to get coordinates where plot point. in other word, undocumented.

Using them is shorthand for getting values from point:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.x
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.y
And translating to position via:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels()

The links above seem completely unrelated.

I tried this to divine what those coordinates provide

```
}, function (chart) { // on complete
var point = chart.series[0].points[8];
chart.renderer.label('.'
, point.plotX.toFixed(0), point.plotY.toFixed(0), 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop)

        .add();

});
```

seems plotX is some point situated a random set of pixels to the left of the chart series point that provides it (about 60ish) and seems to depend on the font you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```
var point = chart.series[0].points[8];
var pxX = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(point.x, true);
var pxY = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(point.y, true);

chart.renderer.label('Max observation', pxX, pxY, 'callout', point.plotX + chart.plotLeft, point.plotY + chart.plotTop);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrzqxvok/) - Notice `.toPixels` works *per Axis*, so you need to determine the pixel representation of point X and point Y separately. The `true` parameter to the function positions the callout based on its point, rather than the top left corner of the callout.